# ng-repeat on ng-table in angularjs. Multiple Dynamic Tables

Tags: json, angularjs, multiple-tables, ngtable

Want to repeat an ng-table and ng rows both from a nested table. How to repeat the table from a nested json. for example json may be :

```
{
"service_info":{
    "service_name":"heading1",
    "sl_id":3,
    "stack":1
},
"instance_info":[
    {
        "instance_id":1,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "instance_id":2,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
},
{
"service_info":{
    "service_name":"heading2",
    "sl_id":3,
    "stack":1
},
"instance_info":[
    {
        "instance_id":1,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "instance_id":2,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

need service info as the table heading and instance info as a table row in ng-table. if I use tableparams in it no data is displayed.

Comment: I've never used ng-table, but I think you'll need an array of tableparam objects; one for each table.  In your javascript, you'll need an array of tableparam objects, so iterate over your json array and use data[i].service_info to construct its tableparams, and just stuff it into your data model as data[i].tableparams.

ng-repeat over the whole thing in your html and do something like <table ng-repeat="dataitem in data" ng-table="{{dataitem.tableparams}}"><tr ng-repeat="stuff_from_tableparams"><td></td</tr> 
etc etc

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch This sounds good, but am looking for a simpler approach. But still I will try it and update this with a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the trick suggested by @GrumbleSnatch I could get the desired result and here it goes.

```
$scope.ilist={
"service_info":{
    "service_name":"heading1",
    "sl_id":3,
    "stack":1
},
"instance_info":[
    {
        "instance_id":1,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "instance_id":2,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
},
{
"service_info":{
    "service_name":"heading2",
    "sl_id":3,
    "stack":1
},
"instance_info":[
    {
        "instance_id":1,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "instance_id":2,
        "possible_actions":{
            "actions":[
                {
                    "action_name":"modify",
                    "action_id":2
                },
                {
                    "action_name":"deprovision",
                    "action_id":3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
};

$scope.tabledata=[];
for (var i=0;i< $scope.ilist.length;i++){

    $scope.tabledata[i]={};
    var datat=$scope.ilist[i];
    $scope.tabledata[i].tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,           
                count: 10          
            }, {
                total: datat.instance_info.length, 
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    $scope.displayingItems=datat.instance_info.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()).length;
                    $defer.resolve(datat.instance_info.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
}
```

and Html goes like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="instanceList in  ilist track by $index">
    <h3>{{instanceList.service_info.service_name}}</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-left alignment" class="table" ng-table="tabledata[$index].tableParams" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <tr ng-repeat="instance in $data">
            <td data-title="'Instance Name'">
                <a style="cursor: pointer; color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
                    {{instanceList.service_info.service_name}}_{{instance.instance_id}}
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please don't copy paste this code. as this particular code is not tested. Understand it so that you can do it easily.